# How to Create a self-contained .exe file from .NET Framework project?

Tags: c#, .net

I am an IT engineer in a company, and I finished a C# .NET Framework forms project. I published the project, and the output is an installer file.

I don't want the installer file, I want to create a standalone .exe file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why? Isn't it better if it installs itself properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open ProjectFolder\bin\Debug after bulid